# Do hallucinogens cause people to jump out of the window?

Tags: recreational-drugs, hallucinations

Back in the 90s, [the DARE program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_Abuse_Resistance_Education) made a big point about how hallucinogenic drugs cause people to jump out the window because they think they can fly, or similar things. Various other sources (such as frequent drug users) claim that the reality is that when people are hallucinating such things they aren't prone to try to make this happen in reality; [this article on LSD fact and fiction](http://psychedelics.com/lsd/lsd-fact-and-fiction/) claims outright that there have been no cases of LSD-induced aeronautics.

My various websearches on this matter do find a handful of articles about people allegedly attempting to jump out the window due to drug use, but it isn't clear that this isn't a case of confirmation bias, and a handful of articles are of course not proof of a systemic problem.

Are there any actual statistics that indicate the rate of self-inflicted defenestration as a result of drug use? In particular, how many out-of-a-window falls are due to confirmed drug use and hallucinations vs., say, it turning out that a roommate or spouse decided to throw them out with LSD as a cover story? And of course, any statistics on how many people attempt to jump out of the window compared to how many times they use hallucinogens are probably hard to come by (or even measure).

Comment: It would be extremely rare, so I doubt there are actual statistics. The only actual case I can remember is probabably a staged one (Frank Olsen): https://www.theguardian.com/world/2012/nov/29/cia-lawsuit-scientist-1950s-death By the way, do you have evidence the DARE program claimed this? The Wikipedia page you link to doesn't mention flying or jumping (out the window or otherwise).

Comment: N.B.: what LangLangC is talking about is related to the Olson file: http://www.bbc.com/news/world-10996838

Comment: @Fizz I don't have any proof of this, just my recollections of the DARE program in my high school in the early 90s.

Comment: +1 for 'LCD-induced aeronautics'

Comment: Another question with hallucination-induced jumping out of windows is whether they did it because they thought they could fly, or whether something inside scared them so much that they though they would be safer outside.

Comment: **_Yes_**, based on personally having witnessed someone trying to do this back in college.  The guy kept loudly announcing that he **"_needed air_"** while he opened a window on the top story of the building and attempted to go through it.  Luckily, he was restrained before being able to do so.  He fought back against those restraining him, desperately trying to get through the window.  Except, I'm not sure exactly what he was on; he didn't wreak of alcohol, and there wasn't an especially strong smoke smell.

Comment: People trying to escape jump out of windows, i would imagine it's a terrible day for someone if they are both on hallucinogens and being deprived of their freedom of movement, the good Shepherd has a scene about it, and there's also this ... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Olson